# Multi stage sign up process with rails and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to create a multi-step sign-up procedure using rails and devise.

Step one, visitors can sign up with email, password and password confirmation.  Email address would need to verified.

Step two, Upon successful email verification I would like to direct the new user to an additional form which would require them to add a username and zip code/postcode. Once this is complete redirect the user to their profile.

Can anyone help explain how this can be done with Devise? or maybe even a tutorial I can follow.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

Devise has `:confirmable` flag for this.

```
# models/user.rb
devise :registerable, :confirmable
```

Also, you will need add this fields to model:

```
# db/migrate/XXXXXXX_devise_migration.rb
# Confirmable
t.string   :confirmation_token
t.datetime :confirmed_at
t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

For more information, please read [this section](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users) of Devise documentation.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have setup Devise with a confirmable option.  So step 1 is fine.  However with step 2 I am struggling because firstly, the new user should only be redirected to the next stage of setup once to choose his username and provide a postcode.  Next time that user logs in it should go straight to the home page.  Secondly both username and postcode are required, if I add required to them straight off, then step 1 fails.  How do I make it so that they are required only after step 1 is complete?

Comment: After user will confirm his email, he will have date in field `user.confirmed_at`. So, if there is date -- show additional form for this user. Assume, you also will want add other field to User model, like `user.form_filled_at` -- to not ask form filling again.

Comment: In your case - you have only one step -- user registration with email confirmation. After email confirmed -- you allowing your user go next to application. But in `application_controller.rb` you will have something, like `before_action :user_filled_additional_form?` and this method `user_filled_additional_form?` will always redirect user to form filling `unless current_user.form_filled_at`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a state machine to record the user's current state. For example, if you have a multi-onboarding sign up flow, for each step in the onboarding process, you could add a different state once they have moved on (e.g., page 1, page 2, page 3, etc). You could even use a gem like AASM - Ruby state machines: https://github.com/aasm/aasm